# Bid-ask spread in order-driven stock market

Tags: stock-exchanges, bid-ask

The bid-ask spread can be used to measure transaction costs in a quote-driven OTC market.  Can one also use the bid-ask spread to measure transaction costs for an **order**-driven market?

Comment: That sounds more like an economic theory question than a personal finance question...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use bid-ask spreads as one of the elements in transaction costs for order-driven markets. They are a good indicator of liquidity for a particular instrument and something that investors should keep in mind when choosing where to put their money; since being able to get in/out of an investment without losing significant capital in the process is a good thing.

A lot of the [debate around whether or not HFT is a good thing](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2014-04-02/high-frequency-trading-may-be-too-efficient), has focused around the estimation of market efficiency by measuring bid-ask spreads.